# Using VUEX necessary with NODE.js REST Backend

Tags: rest, vue.js, frontend, vuex

I´m not very experienced with Frontend/Backend Architecture, but i created a simple REST Backend with NODE.js and want to build up a Frontend based on Vue.js and Framework7.

So do you recommend using VUEX there? Or how do you deal with the sessions or the different requests you sending to the Backend?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use Vuex, but I'd suggest using Vuex. Here's an example using Vuex and rest api.

**In store/actions.js**

```
import {
  fetchSomething,
} from '../api/index.js';

export const actions = {

  getSomething({ commit }) {
    fetchSomething().then((something) => {
      commit('UPATED_SOMETHING', something);
    });
  },

}
```

**In api/index.js**

```
export const fetchSomething = () => {

  const url = 'Some endpoint';

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    axios.get(url).then((res) => {
      const data = res.data;
      resolve(data);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  })
 
}
```

**In store/mutations.js**

```
export const mutations = {

  UPATED_SOMETHING(state, data) {
   state.something = data;
  },
}
```

**In store/index.js**

```
import { getters } from './getters'
import { actions } from './actions'
import { mutations } from './mutations'

// initial state
const state = {
  something: null,
}

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations,
}
```

**In store/getters.js**

```
export const getters = {

  getSomething: state => {
    return state.something;
  },

}
```

Comment: alright, this would be the way where i can store e.g. the bearer token which i get after login request to rest api? or is here a different way? i will have to read in the official docs i guess to understand the whole mechanism

Comment: Sure, you could store a bearer token in the Vuex store. However, the Vuex store will reset if you refresh the page. I would store the token in a cookie but I would still use Vuex to accomplish this.